# Configuring multiple azure sql databases in spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, azure-sql-database

I am trying to configure two datasources which use the same azure sql username/password but different urls/databases. I am using the @Primary annotation and split up the data access layers into their own folders but only the config without @Primary gets configured.

DataSource1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = Constants.BASE_PAKAGE,
entityManagerFactoryRef = Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
transactionManagerRef= Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public DataSourceConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
    private Environment environment;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }
   
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource1.dialect"));
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages(Constants.ENTITY_PATH)
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager sqlserverTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier(Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(sqlserverEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    protected HikariDataSource dataSource() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource1.driver"));
        config.setJdbcUrl(this.buildSnowflakeJDBCUrl());
        config.setUsername(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource1.username"));
        config.setPassword(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource1.password"));
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private String buildSnowflakeJDBCUrl() {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource1.url"));
        return url.toString();
    }
   
}
```

and DataSource2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = Constants.BASE_PACKAGE2,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlserver2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "sqlserver2TransactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfiguration2 {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public PhDataSourceConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlserver2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource2.dialect"));
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages(Constants.ENTITY_PATH2)
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlserver2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager sqlserverTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("sqlserver2EntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(sqlserverEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    protected HikariDataSource dataSource() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource2.driver"));
        config.setJdbcUrl(this.buildJDBCUrl());
        config.setUsername(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource2.username"));
        config.setPassword(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource2.password"));
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private String buildJDBCUrl() {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append(environment.getProperty("sqlserver.datasource2.url"));
        return url.toString();
    }

}
```

is it an issue because they are both reading from the same user/password for azure sql? How can I get both of the configs to work?

Comment: Some of the bean names overlap (using the method name if not specified), so the last `@Bean` processed would win.  Try explicitly naming the beans, and `@Qualifier` the correct bean instance is injected where needed.

Comment: you were right on, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Andrew S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650475/andrew-s). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Some of the bean names overlap (using the method name if not
> specified), so the last @Bean processed would win. Try explicitly
> naming the beans, and @Qualifier the correct bean instance is injected
> where needed.